# Application specific UDP datagrams in MatLab

Tags: java, matlab, udp

I am trying to receive real time integer values from piece of software that supports UDP transmission in MatLab. There is a network streaming protocol specification document for the software here, among all the files I mention later in this post: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIClEmQisqFWjJ3ajBMUG96Nkk

I found a reliable, high speed implementation of java in MatLab for receiving UDP datagrams, judp.m .

Now, I have tried different variations of fread to interpret the datagrams after they have been received and stored by MatLab.

mvnstream.txt contains the data saved using fprintf implemented in "javaUDP.m". I also have tried using char('data') in mvnstream1.txt, which gave me the correct header "MXTP20" corresponding to the joint angle data I want to see in MatLab as floating point integers. The problem is that everything succeeding the header still looks like gibberish.

On page 12 of 16 in the MVN studio real time document, section 2.7.1, it describes the joint angle data as having 20 bytes per segment, with a breakdown of which bytes correspond to which data. I know this 
is likely the key, but I'm at the limit of my understanding as a mechanical engineer. Any pointers would be great. Thank you.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You seemingly intend to develop your own networking implementation for the MVN device. Have you considered using one provided by the manufacturer? In case you have access to their SDK, you could just create a MEX interface to the provided library. In my opinion this could be considerably easier than what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion; I was able to find the libraries provided in their SDK release. Now I just have to learn how to implement them in MatLab like you described; it's my first time having to do this. If you have any good examples of MEX interface creation with existing libraries please let me know. I've been doing my own research but I haven't found many clear explanations yet.